# NSURLConnection - didReceiveData didn't get called - iOS & ARC

Tags: ios, http, ios6, nsurlconnection

I'm currently experimenting with the twitter streaming api and i'm trying to get a stream with `NSURLConnection`. As it doesn't work with twitter, i simplified everything and tried to get some source-code out of google's website, but this doesn't work neither.

The connection starts and ends, but without calling the `didReceiveData` delegate. I'm sure i'm missing something. Hope you guy's can help me!

In the header: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate, NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender>`

And in the body:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLConnection *connection;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL {
    NSLog(@"Stream finished.");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", dataString);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Connection failed!");
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into a new app, and I got the log, "Stream Finished".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of thoughts.

1. Your declaration of [`connectionDidFinishLoading`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connectionDidFinishLoading%3a) doesn't look right. The standard [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method does not have a `destinationURL` parameter:

   ```
   - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
   {
       NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
   }
   ```
2. Given the presence of `NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender`, if you're expecting a challenge (which you won't get with Google web site) then you'd obviously handle it accordingly:

   ```
   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
   {
       // For example, if you have a userid/password to use, see if this is the first 
       // challenge, and then tell NSURLConnection to try using those credentials, and if 
       // it failed a second time, you might just cancel the authentication challenge.

       if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0) {
           NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:kUserID password:kPassword persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
           [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
       } else {
           [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
       }
   }
   ```
3. By the way, you do not want to call [`start`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW4) method when you use `initWithRequest` or `connectionWithRequest`. It's only needed if you do a simple `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` and instruct it to *not* `startImmediately`.
4. Anyway, I used the following and it works fine:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
       [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
   }

   - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
   {
       NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
   }

   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
       NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       NSLog(@"%s: %@", __FUNCTION__, dataString);
   }

   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
       NSLog(@"%s error=%@", __FUNCTION__, error);
   }
   ```

Comment: THANK'S for your answer.. The problem was the connectionDidFInishLoading.. I followed up a tutorial on some site, where the other delegate was used.. I removed it and added your's. It works now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Someone said here that it was their SOAP format
[NSURLConnection delegate method: didReceiveData not called ...Why ?? (iPhone SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923190/nsurlconnection-delegate-method-didreceivedata-not-called-why-iphone-sdk)

This also may be what you are looking for
[NSURLConnection didReceiveData not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420469/nsurlconnection-didreceivedata-not-called)

Comment: Sorry i missed something during copy & passed. I used [connection start]. But previously i also tried your method. Doesn't work.. I will update the question.

Comment: I suspect that that first one is simply that they had a bug in their server code that prevented a response from being generated at all and the second one is that they tried to invoke `NSURLConnection` from a background queue (which is problematic if you don't use a run loop ... easier to just initiate from the main queue).

Answer (score 0):

Your NSURLConnection local variable `connection` is going out of scope at the end of `viewDidLoad`. Add a property to your ViewController to hold the NSURLConnection variable in scope.

Comment: That's not necessary. It's retained for you for the duration of the connection. Sometimes it's useful to have that around, but generally you don't need to do that.